# Constant Current LED Driver Output Control using PWM

Tags: led, mosfet, pwm, led-driver, constant-current

I want to control the brightness of a led which is powered by a constant current driver.

On utilizing a MOSFET and pwm signal from an arduino uno the led starts to fade in as the duty cycle increases. But the problem is that the led "blinks" at lower duty cycle and stabilizes only at about the full brightness. (The constant current driver that came with led is used here).

Please suggest me a new circuit in which I am able to avoid the blinking issue while utilizing the driver that came with the led.

Also, take a look at this : [how to control constant current led driver output with pwm?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67929/how-to-control-constant-current-led-driver-output-with-pwm?rq=1)

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2filAGN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What's the frequency of your PWM?

Comment: The frequency is 980Hz

Comment: "Constant current" driver is making me suspicious. How can it be constant if you are breaking it with the MOSFET? The idea of using the driver is that you can control *it* to change the current and the brightness.

Comment: Most constant current LED drivers I've seen have dimness control at the driver itself - something that throttles the output between 0 and 130mA. Many are I2C/SPI controlled, but you might find one that accepts PWM as a control signal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, what I am saying is that the driver that came with led is a constant current driver. I just followed the usual arduino high voltage pwm control circuit that is used to control 12v led strips.

Comment: You should tell us more about this driver.

Comment: Sure will post a photo and other details...

Comment: @ChrisFernandez, My driver doesn't have all those features, its just a basic one.

Comment: Anyhow, the circuit as presented *can't*  be driven by constant current source. It can only work properly with regular voltage supply.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can you suggest me a circuit that varies current using pwm please, and what do you thing is causing led blink issue ?

Comment: Using this driver? I can only think of placing a resistor in parallel to the LED+MOSFET to "absorb" the "extra" current. But it will reduce the maximum brightness level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88753/discussion-between-electric-90-and-eugene-sh).

Comment: You simply need a constant current source with built-in dimming features. There are countless models available, from trustworthy OEMs all the way to Alibaba no-name products for $1.